# Miniconda has replaced both python and python3 paths

Tags: python, debian, miniconda

Basically, my problem is that I installed Miniconda recently to use the Scrapy package. In doing so, it seems to have infiltrated the paths for both python 2 and python 3. For instance:

```
root@kali:~# type python
python is hashed (/opt/miniconda3/bin/python)
root@kali:~# type python3
python3 is /opt/miniconda3/bin/python3
root@kali:~# python --version
Python 3.6.0 :: Continuum Analytics, Inc.
```

It seems to me that the most effective method of dealing with this is to point the path back to the original python2 and python 3 directories, however, in searching, the solutions invariably say don't mess with the path links. I have added an environment path to my .profile file, but that doesn't seem to have had any noticeable effect.

The problem first became apparent in installing through apt, when standard libraries weren't being found, presumably because this is a mini version, so I can't leave it as is.

Thanks